# Replace &nbsp; with a blank or empty string PHP

Tags: php, str-replace

Well, I have tried these and it seems that none of them are working, my example string is

```
 $text_description="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;Hello world! lorel ipsum";

 $text_description= str_replace("&nbsp;"," ",$text_description);
 $text_description = preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]+;/i"," ",$text_description);
 $text_description=html_entity_decode($text_description);
```

Comment: Is that `<pre>` part of your code, or an artifact of copying/pasting into StackOverflow's WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: &nbsp; was not rendering properly so I had to use that <pre> tag

Comment: I think `&nbsp;` behave like empty string. isn't it?

Comment: yes, but when I need to trim it, it does not get trimmed

Comment: @diEcho it doesn't line break like an empty string would

Comment: The str_replace and preg_replace examples both work for me (each `&nbsp;` is replaced by a space). Do these lines not work for you if you run them all by themselves? What do you get instead?

Comment: its very strange, they do not get replaced at all

Comment: I'm sure you're didn't tested your code. Because it works fine

Comment: I did tested it, the issue was with strip_tags function, it somehow generated those tags and using all the above methods I was unable to replace &nbsp;, I finally used javascript to replace all &nbsp; symbols

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$text_description="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;Hello world! lorel ipsum";
$text_description = str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $text_description);
echo $text_description;
```

Output:

> Hello world! lorel ipsum

Comment: Not working with this - "../projectGallery/1434565856cam&nbsp;swiming1_BigPH.jpg"

Comment: Yes it does: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c143ec402c7cb314e6d890e9ad9ba2c8c5d13eef

Comment: I used this code as it is but got this &nbsp; all the time.

Answer (score 4):

A little late to answer but hopefully might help someone else.  The most important thing while extracting content from html is to use [utf8_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) in php. Then all other string operations become a breeze.  Even foreign characters can be replaced by directly copy pasting characters from browser into the php code.  The following function replaces `&nbsp;` with empty character.  Then all extra white spaces are replaced with a single white space using `preg_replace()`. Leading and trailing white spaces are removed in the end using `trim()`.

```
function clean($str)
{       
    $str = utf8_decode($str);
    $str = str_replace("&nbsp;", "", $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$str);
    $str = trim($str);
    return $str;
}

$html = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;Hello world! lorel ipsum";
$output = clean($html);
echo $output;
```

> Hello world! lorel ipsum

Comment: utf8_decode will deprecate. Use mb_convert_encoding instead

Answer (score 3):

You Can just [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) wich allow you to replace all html entities to their applicable characters for example :

```
 $HtmlText="it's&nbsp;Working \"Correctly\"";
 $MyText=html_entity_decode($HtmlText);
 echo $MyText; // "it's Working "Correctly"
```

I Wish that is helpfull ! ;)

Comment: html_entity_decode is a native php string function; look here: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.html-entity-decode.php
check your dev env